# Which of the following maps are diﬀerentiable everywhere?

Tags: real-analysis

Which of the following maps are diﬀerentiable everywhere?
(a) $f(x) = |x|^3x, x ∈ \mathbb{R}$.
(b) $f : \mathbb{R} → \mathbb{R}$ such that $|f(x) − f(y)| ≤ |x − y|^{\sqrt{2}}$for all $x ,y ∈\mathbb{ R}$.
(c) $f(x) = x^3\sin \frac{1}{\sqrt{|x|}}$when $x \ne 0$ and $f(0) = 0$.

---

I know that (a) is differentiable everywhere but can not confirm about the others.

Comment: suppose you have $|f(x) − f(y)| ≤ |x − y|^2$ then can you say something?

Answer (score 0):

About (b) you can prove that $f'=0$ so $f$ is actually constant.

For (c) write the derivative of $f$ in $x\neq 0$ and check if the limit of the derivative exists for $x\to 0$.